# AWS glue Python ETL Log/print data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue

I'm trying to ingest some data from SQLServer to AWS Dynamo but I'm getting some issues due to some duplicated keys, the table is created with a partition Key and a Sort Key.

I would like to be able to print somehow the list of items of the batch which are causing the error `Provided list of item keys contains duplicates`.
I'm not being able even to print the data in the logs any clue to print the data or identify the duplicated item??
can I catch the Dynamo API request made by the Glue dynamic frame?

This is my code, I just removed the mappings to make the post short.

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME"])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
logger = glueContext.get_logger()
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)

database_name = "DB_NAME"
compamy_id = "2190"
environment = "dev"


##########################################
#           Table Acuerdos_pago          #
##########################################

SQLServertable_acuerdos_pago = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database=database_name,
    table_name="adi_dtm.acuerdos_pago",
    transformation_ctx="SQLServertable_acuerdos_pago",
)

ApplyMapping_acuerdos_pago = ApplyMapping.apply(
    frame=SQLServertable_acuerdos_pago,
    mappings=[],
    transformation_ctx="ApplyMapping_acuerdos_pago",
)

DynamoDB_acuerdos_pago = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame=ApplyMapping_acuerdos_pago,
    connection_type="dynamodb",
    connection_options={
        "dynamodb.output.tableName": f"powerbi_sinco_{compamy_id}_acuerdos_pago_{environment}",
        "dynamodb.throughput.write.percent": "1.0"
    },
    transformation_ctx="DynamoDB_acuerdos_pago"
)

print("Contents of write_dynamic_frame dynamic frame")

DynamoDB_acuerdos_pago.toDF().show()

job.commit()
```

I tried to use the `logger` to print the whole context.
Also i tried to convert the glue context to an Apache Spark DataFrame and use the `.show` method to print the data but not luck.

Thanks in advance for all the help you could bring to me.

Answer (score 0):

Glue is abstracting BatchWriteItem API through it's write dynamic frame method. The exception you are getting us caused by 2 items within the batch sharing the same partition and sort key. If they were in different underlying batches, the operation would succeed but your data would be compromised as one item would overwrite the other.

A better solution is use the SQL command `DISTINCT` based on the columns which are now your partition and sort key combo, as this will ensure that only 1 item exists for each primary key before writing to DynamoDB.

Comment: Hi @Lee thanks I would take a look into the approach you mention.
But still is not clear if it is possible to catch the BatchWriteItem operation which have the duplicated Item or even catch the whole dataset to find the duplicate data and fix it on the source, it will help a lot to troubleshoot future issues being able to log that data.

Comment: You can't easily, unless you're good with spark you can parallelize the save operations into very small chunks and print the dynamic frame, but it's not a good approach. It's best to just `SELECT DISTINCT`